# Execute a part of code in specified time

Tags: java, swing

I want to make an animation using java swing. I have a for loop that changes the location of an image slightly. My question is **How can I make the each loop execution takes the specified amount of time?**.
Its what I've done but I don't know how to use `wait()` and don't know is there a better way.

```
// inside of a MyJPanel class extending JPanel
for (int i = 0; i < FJframe.FRAMES; i++){
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    animationFrame = i;
    this.repaint();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long remainder = (end - start);
    System.out.println(remainder);
    try {
        this.wait(200 - remainder);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

### Edit

here my overrided Jpanel `PaintComponent()`:
    //some drawing
    drawChanges(g, getDelta(), animationFrame, FJPanle.FRAMES);

And inside drawChanges(Graphics g, ArrayList deltas, int frame, int frames):

```
// a switch_case with cases similar to this one.
case AGENT_ATTACK:
// tu phase badi animation e kill
    //drawImage(g2d, map[delta.getCell().x][delta.getCell().y], attacker);
    source = map[delta.getSource().x][delta.getSource().y];
    dest = map[delta.getDestination().x][delta.getDestination().y];
    distanceX =  dest.getCenter().x -
            source.getCenter().x;
    distanceY = dest.getCenter().y -
            source.getCenter().y;
    if (counter < frames / 2){
        g2d.drawImage(ImageHolder.attacker, source.getBounds().x + (int)(((float)counter/frames) * distanceX),
                source.getBounds().y + (int)(((float)counter/frames) * distanceY),
                null);
    }
    else{
        g2d.drawImage(ImageHolder.attacker, dest.getBounds().x - (int)(((float)counter/frames) * distanceX),
                dest.getBounds().y - (int)(((float)counter/frames) * distanceY),
                null);
    }
    break;
```

---

I want each loop takes, for example, exactly 200 miliseconds. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Using wait will pause your thread. It might be better to use a Timer on a loop.

Comment: You are going to get an `IllegalArgumentException` if your `remainder` is greater than 200.

Comment: While there are other alternatives (like the Timer) that might be more appropriate for certain application cases, and some details (like the one gla3dr mentioned above) that should be fixed, there is nothing wrong with this code *in general*. What is your question about in particular? EDIT: Well, maybe use `Thread#sleep(...)`  instead of `this#wait(...)`

Comment: @gla3dr: yes, that's right but I don't know any better way. Perhaps you could guide me.

Comment: @Marco13: I am writing the graphic part of a simple game and I want to show unit movements with animation. So I need to repaint the with the changes every (for example) one tenth of a second.

Comment: @alireza Try looking into whiskeyspider's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not an acceptable answer, but too long for a comment:

There are several options, depending on the actual intention. The pattern that you described is not uncommon for a "simple game loop". In this case, a code that is similar to the one that you posted is run in an own thread, and regularly triggers a `repaint()` in order to paint the updated game state. In your case, it seems that *only* the `animationFrame` variable is increased. For such a simple action, the alternatives that have already been mentioned may be sufficient:

- As suggested by whiskeyspider in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21860250/ : You could use a `java.util.Timer` with a `TimerTask` that only updated the `animationFrame`
- Alternatively, you could use a `javax.swing.Timer` whose `ActionListener` updates the `animationFrame`. This *might* be advantageous here, because you can be sure that the update of the `animationFrame` happens on the event dispatch thread. Thus, the update of this variable can not interfere with its *usage* in the painting method, for example
- But as mentioned in the comments: An own thread that executed the code that you already posted (with the minor adaptions) is also feasible and not "wrong" per se - but note that in this case (similar to when using a `java.util.Timer`) you might have to take care of the synchronization on your own

---

**EDIT**: Based on the edited question: Similar to what I expected, you are using the `animationFrame` in your painting method. The crucial point here are the details about how the `animationFrame` variable is used. For example, if your `paintComponent` method looks like this

```
class MyJPanel extends JPanel {
    private int animationFrame = 0;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 

        drawChanges(g, getDelta(), animationFrame, FJPanle.FRAMES);
        drawSomethingElse(g, animationFrame, ...);
        drawEvenMore(g, animationFrame, ...);
    }

    ...
}
```

then it may happen that the value of `animationFrame` is changed (by another thread, possibly the `java.util.Timer` thread) **while** the `paintComponent` method is executed. That means that `drawChanges` and `drawSomethingElse` may receive *different* values for `animationFrame`. This may cause rendering artefacts (misplaced images, tearing between tiles etc).

This could either be avoided by using a `javax.swing.Timer` (because then, the updates of `animationFrame` will be done on the same thread as the one that executes `paintComponent`), or by making sure that *all* painting operations use the same value of `animationFrame` - roughly like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 

        int animationFrameUsedForAllPainting = animationFrame;
        drawChanges(g, getDelta(), animationFrameUsedForAllPainting , FJPanle.FRAMES);
        drawSomethingElse(g, animationFrameUsedForAllPainting , ...);
        drawEvenMore(g, animationFrameUsedForAllPainting , ...);
    }
```

But apart from that, there is not sooo much difference between the aforementioned approaches in this case. So for simplicity, you could use the `javax.swing.Timer` (or the `java.util.Timer` when you make sure that the update is "thread safe" regarding the painting operations).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About my code, animationFrame is not the only thing changing. Based on this variable alot of locations (about 100) change in a function called in JPanel `PaintComponent()`.

Comment: OK, then the aspect of synchronization becomes more important. You have to make sure that a change in this variable does not interfere with what you are doing in the `paintComponent` method. Maybe you can edit your question to describe what you are doing there in addition to increasing the `animationFrame`, and possibly show a short (!) sketch of how you are *using* the `animationFrame` variable.

Comment: @alireza Updated my answer with an EDIT as well.

Answer (score 2):

Look into using a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).  For example, the [`scheduleAtFixedRate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) method.

Comment: A `java.util.Timer` *might* be problematic here, because the question is about Swing, and you'll have to consider the Swing threading policies. A `javax.swing.Timer` *might* be more appropriate here (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), but this probably has to be fleshed out in the comments...